# Why does a checkbox always return the same value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

**Edit3:** Before more people keep downvoting this, please note this is **not** a duplicate question.

I'm working on a site that needs a table full of checkboxes and each one needs to be toggled on/off. Sometimes toggling one on needs to toggle others off and so on.

I did not build the base code, but since it was rather messy with all the logic going on, I decided to make some work like radios so we only have one base function to make much of the logic work.

I also have a function to enable/disable some checkboxes. It all works nicely, no problems at all.

But now there's another thing in play which is a text input. If a certain value is selected in it, some checkboxes automatically get turned on/off and locked in. The same base function is used to do this. But when a checkbox gets disabled with this, and then re-enabled, the following function keeps returning always true **only for that checkbox**:

```
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

        // Make checkboxes with names work like radios (radios can't be toggled off)
        if ($(this).attr("name")) {
            // Save clicked toggle value
            var selected_toggle = $(this).attr('value');

            // disable all and then toggle clicked one on
            if ($('input[value="'+selected_toggle+'"]').prop("checked")) {
                console.log("This is checked");
                $('input:checkbox[name='+$(this).attr('name')+']').each(function() {
                    toggle_checkbox($(this).attr('value'), 'disabled');
                });
                toggle_checkbox(selected_toggle, 'enabled', 'on');
            }
            // Enable them all back if unchecking
            else {
                console.log("This is unchecked");
                $('input:checkbox[name='+$(this).attr('name')+']').each(function() {
                    toggle_checkbox($(this).attr('value'), 'enabled');
                });
                $(this).parent().toggleClass("on");
            }
        }
        else {
            // Toggle them on or off
            $(this).parent().toggleClass("on");
        }
    });
```

The obvious thing would be to say "something is different when locking/unlocking that checkbox", but it's all the same function and same way all other toggles get disabled, this is used from toggle_checkbox function:

```
function toggle_checkbox(toggle, value, on, lock) {

    // Disable the toggle completely
    if (value == 'disabled') {
        $('input[value="'+toggle+'"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('input[value="'+toggle+'"]').parents('li').addClass('disabled');
        $('input[value="'+toggle+'"]').parent().removeClass('on');
        $('input[value="'+toggle+'"]').prop('checked', false);
    }
    // Enable a toggle back
    if (value == 'enabled') {
        $('input[value="'+toggle+'"]').parents('li').removeClass('disabled');

        // Turn it on
        if (on == 'on') {
            $('input[value="'+toggle+'"]').parent().addClass('on');
            $('input[value="'+toggle+'"]').prop('checked', true);
        }
        // Lock it on or remove disabled
        if (lock == 'lock') {
            $('input[value="'+toggle+'"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('input[value="'+toggle+'"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }
}
```

When I remove the above code for name attributes, the checkbox works fine. Yet though every other checkbox returns Checked/unchecked properly, when clicking that specific un-disabled one, it always returns "this is checked".

I was using is(":checked") before, changing to prop made no difference.

**Edit:** As said in the comments, using prop or attr didn't make a difference. This is the code that is locking the checkbox that gets "stuck":

```
function set_hint_toggles(type, state) { 

    if (type == 'apples') { // Set when you select something with apples
        toggle_checkbox('pears', 'disabled');
        toggle_checkbox('apples', 'enabled', 'on', 'lock');
        toggle_checkbox('oranges', 'disabled');
    }
    if (state == 'off') { // This is set when a reset button is pressed
        var toggles_type = $('#hidden-input-with-value').val();
        toggle_checkbox(toggles_type, 'enabled'); // This checkbox gets stuck, all others continue working
        $('#text-input').removeAttr("disabled"); // Allows to type something again
    }
}
```

**Edit2:** After trying Marvin answer I got a slighly different result that could help finding what's wrong:

This stuck checkbox has a "checked" and "disabled" state. When the reset button is clicked, disabled gets removed, but it remains checked (or should). When I tried to click the checkbox with the above code after reset, it was like it got re-checked once, and then kept stuck with checked.

Using [0].disabled  = false, I can then keep toggling the checkbox on and off, but no js gets activated for it, and every click still returns checked.

**Edit4:** When attempting to use

```
toggle_checkbox(toggles_type, 'disabled');
toggle_checkbox(toggles_type, 'enabled');
```

In the code that makes the checkbox get stuck (set_hint_toggles(off) function above), it gets disabled only. Afterwards, this checkbox keeps returning always false instead of always true.

Comment: When you set the attribute, the property is set as well, and when you remove the attribute, the property is not removed, you have to set it to false, which is why you should be using `prop`

Comment: Yet, why it only happens on one situation, and not all? What's the difference?

Comment: @adeneo - That fixed it! Could you post it as an answer so I can mark solved? There's still a long way to go for learning proper js for me.

Comment: Not quite sure what fixed it, but post an answer yourself where you explain the issue as best you can, and the solution, for prosperity and other users having the same issue

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103767/discussion-on-question-by-forty-why-does-a-checkbox-always-return-the-same-value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It truly was something wrong in the first block of code I posted. I'm now using this based off Adeneo's suggestion on changing the selectors and it's working perfectly:

```
// Search checkbox toggles
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

    // Make checkboxes with names work like radios (radios can't be toggled off)
    if ($(this).attr("name")) {

        if (this.checked) {
            $('[name='+ this.name +']').each(function() {
                toggle_disabled( this.value, 'disabled');
            });
            toggle_disabled( this.value, 'enabled', 'on');
        }
        else {
            $('[name='+ this.name +']').each(function() {
                toggle_disabled( this.value, 'enabled');
            });
            $(this).parent().toggleClass("on");
        }
    }
    // Else if no name, just toggle on class
    else {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("on");
    }
});
```

I believe the problem was in the selector used for testing if the checkbox was on.

I'm also using prop on everything else now, but this did not change anything and does not seem like it had to do with the problem at all. The other suggestions also did not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a litle tip that you can use to improve your code.. Without a jsfiddle or some example, i'm afraid that i can't help you more than this. You should try using the DOM native api to set the disabled item

```
$('input[value="'+toggle+'"]')[0].disabled //returns if the element is disabled

$('input[value="'+toggle+'"]')[0].disabled  = true //set element as disabled or not
```

The same works for the checked attribute.

```
$('input[value="'+toggle+'"]')[0].checked //returns if the element is checked

$('input[value="'+toggle+'"]')[0].checked = true //set element as checked or not
```

Comment: This is working great, thanks. But that checkbox still gets "stuck". There's something new in the way it does though, which explains some of its behavior before. This stuck checkbox has a "checked" and "disabled" state. When I click the reset button, disabled gets removed, but it remains checked. When I tried to click it with previous code, it was like it got checked once, and then kept stuck with checked. Now using [0].disabled  = false, I can see it's removing disabled **and** checked. I can then keep toggling it on and off, but no js gets activated for it.

Comment: And just to note it, the jQuery version would be `$('input[value="'+toggle+'"]').eq(0).prop('checked', true)`

Comment: Tried that too and still no difference besides what I explained in edit2 :/